# Таблица с заголовками столбцов

Tags: android, java

Как в Android создать таблицу с "шапкой"? Добавил в приложение таблицу с помощью `TableLayout`, но такой возможности не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView />
    </TableRow>
    <ScrollView>      
    <TableLayout>          
        <TableRow>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>     
</TableLayout>
```

Будет отдельная таблица под шапку.

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает выделить особенным образом первую строку таблицы? Например шрифт сделать жирный, поставить рамку.

Comment: Потому что если таблица больше, чем видимая область, должен появляться скроллер. И обычно он отображается таким образом, что шапка остается неподвижной, то есть скроллит только область данных таблицы.